# how to find f(21) of the following probability generating function

Tags: probability, generating-functions

I have a pgf that seems to me would take more than 5 minutes to find f(21) of. Does anyone know how to compute f(21) of this pgf within the specified time?

```
f(x) = (x+x^2+x^3+x^4+x^5+x^6+x^7)^7/7^5
```

you could derive 21 times and divide by 21! which would take forever. The coefficient would be f(21). Any ideas?

Comment: This isn't a probability generating function. The probabilities don't add up to 1. Also, it doesn't look like you're really looking for $f(21)$. $f(21)$ is a completely different value from the coefficient of $x^{21}$, which is what you really seem to be looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You want:
\begin{align}
[x^{21}] \frac{x^7 (1 - x^7)^7}{(1 - x)^7}
  &= [x^{14}] (1 - x^7)^7 \sum_{n \ge 0} \binom{-7}{n} (-1)^n x^n \\
  &= [x^{14}] (1 - 7 x^7 + 21 x^{14} - \ldots) 
                 \sum_{n \ge 0} \binom{n + 7 - 1}{7 - 1} x^n \\
  &= \binom{20}{6} - 7 \binom{13}{6} + 21 \binom{6}{6} \\
  &= 26769
\end{align}
The value you are looking for is:
$$
\frac{26769}{7^5}
$$

Comment: no friend, you are lost somewhere. This question has a real non-zero probability. The highest degree of this polynomial should be 49, approximately

Comment: @JqueryNinja, misread. I plead no coffee.